# colorbox popup is unable to load google map form an inline div in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, internet-explorer-7, colorbox

the following code loads google map form an inline div to colorbox popup window in all versions of modern browsers but it is unable to load the map in a backdated browser like ie7.

```
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=/////////;sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(xxxxxxxx,yyyyyyy);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(xxxxxxxx,yyyyyyy),
    zoom:10,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });

marker.setMap(map);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:"hello world
  });

infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".inline").colorbox({
  inline:true,
  href:"#googleMap",
  fixed:true,
  onComplete: function(){
     initialize();

  }
    });
});
</script>

</head>
```

---

```
<body>
<div style="display:none;">
<div id="googleMap" style="width:600px;height:500px;">
</div>
</div>

<a class='inline' href="#googleMap">Google Map</a>
</body>
```

---

i'm pointing how and where exactly the js errors are noticed by ie7 console in the following blocks of code:

```
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  .....*Error:Expected identifier, string or number...});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".inline").colorbox({
  inline:true,
  href:"#googleMap",
  fixed:true,
  onComplete: function(){
    ........*Error:Object expected...... initialize();

  }
    });
});
```

any idea why it's happening and how to resolve it?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to not use the inline property (old IE struggles with moving certain kinds of content around in the DOM), and instead try using the html property.  Then use onComplete to initialize your script:

```
$(".inline").colorbox({
  html:$('#googleMap').clone().attr('id', 'popupMap'),
  fixed:true,
  onComplete: initialize
});
```

You'll need to edit initialize() to target #popupMap instead of #googleMap.  Another alternative would be to put it in an iframe.

Comment: unfortunately google map doesn't open in colorbox when i add html option to jQuery call function and change other relevant codes accordingly. the blocks of code i posted in my question are working quite fine in `ie7` after i modified these as mentioned in my previous comment. yes colorbox iframe is absolutely good and hassle free for google map iframe code. thanks,

Answer (score 0):

IE is picky when it comes to object literals. Try removing the comma:

```
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:myCenter,
             //here  ^
```

Alsp, you are missing a double quote here:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:"hello world
```

Should be

```
content:"hello world"
```

Comment: `"hello world` was a typing mistake. i tried `position:myCenter,` without comma before i posted my question here. can there be any other reasons why ie7 is unable to fetch the map content from inline div. by the way, the code works fine with all other inline contents in ie7 except google map. thanks,

Comment: @SilentPond Since you dont have much code, the easiest fix would probably be to use the code from https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple, which works in ie7, and add your other stuff one by one. Shouldnt be much work.

Comment: i fixed the problem. i only had to define pixel level height & width in `jQuery` call function and change
`<div id="googleMap" style="width:600px;height:500px;">` to `<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:100%;">`. thanks,